# Problems with fetching and parsing using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I try to fetch this server: http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/?format=json
to a backbone.js collection.
Then I try to console.log it, but it's not working.
It is very important to me, please help.

NEWS: I figured out it's something with JSONP. will be glad to hear more information about that. thanks.

this is parts of my code in short:

```
window.ProjectList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Project,

    url:"http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects",

    parse: function(response) {
         return response.objects;
  }


});
```

another part:

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.projectList = new ProjectList();
        this.projectList.fetch({success : function() {console.log(this.projectList);    }});


        this.homeListView = new HomeListView({model: this.projectList});
    }

});
```

Comment: I see that you're creating a new homeListView and passing into it `model: this.projectList` and yet, `this.projectList` is a collection. Not a model. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you would want to do something more like this:

```
window.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
url:"http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/?format=json" 

}); 

window.ProjectList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: Project,
url:"http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/?format=json"

});

window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
},

render: function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log(self.collection);
    return this; 
}

});

var project = new Project();
var collection = new ProjectList();
collection.fetch({
        success: function(result_collection, resp) {
            var view = new HomeView ({  collection: result_collection });
            view.render();
        }
 });
```

Comment: Hey. I figured out it's something with JSONP. will be glad to hear more information about that. thanks.

Comment: Ahh interesting. Can you try changing the link to http://cshosting.webfactional.com/api/v1/projects/?format=json&callback=? to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

The `this` on the `fetch` callback is not going to refer to your `HomeView` instance. Try using another variable to ensure you are referencing the desired object.

```
initialize:function () {
    var self = this;
    this.projectList = new ProjectList();
    this.projectList.fetch({success : function() {console.log(self.projectList);    }});


    this.homeListView = new HomeListView({model: this.projectList});
}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, please describe what happens. Use the webkit inspector's network tab to make sure the correct GET request and response are being called. Make sure your `parse` function is being called and the `response` object is what you expect.

Comment: Another way to access the collection is simply to give the collection and response arguments to your success callback. `success: function(collection, response) { console.log(collection); console.log(response); });` But the technique Peter mentions is also valid and I use this all the time. Despite thousands of lines of code, I still fall victim to the "Oops... `this` isn't the `this` I thought it was issue." It's a big gotcha. Some people like `that` instead of `self` but I'm in Peter's camp and like using `self` ;-)

Comment: Hey. I figured out it's something with JSONP. will be glad to hear more information about that. thanks.